# select a date between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I hope somebody can help me I am new in sql database.
I have the following table:

```
--------------------------------------
id      from         to        version
---------------------------------------
0        01.01.70    31.12.79     v1    
1        01.01.80    31.12.89     v2
```

Now I would like to reach the following behavior:

when the user selected some date then the version should be returned, where the selected user date is between the corresponding `from` and `to` dates.

examples:

```
user_date = 01.01.70 ------> v1 should be returned
user_date = 01.01.75 ------> v1 should be returned
user_date = 31.12.79 ------> v1 should be returned
user_date = 01.01.80 ------> v2 should be returned
user_date = 01.01.85 ------> v2 should be returned
user_date = 31.12.89 ------> v2 should be returned
```

I tried this

```
select version from versions_table where user_date between from and to;
```

Comment: what was the result of your attempt?

Comment: is the data type of the from and to a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass a variable into the query - depending on your programming language this is easily accomplished.  Substitute .

```
select version
from versions_table
where to_date('<myInputDate>', 'dd.mm.yy') between to_date('from', 'mm.dd.yy') and to_date('to', 'mm.dd.yy');
```

Make sure to substitute the date you are interested in for  (no carets "<>").

[edit]  If you don't to_date them, it will perform an alphabetic ordering, which will cause issues with the query.

Answer (score 3):

`from` could be a bad idea for a column name. 
You could test this SQL Query:

```
SELECT version 
FROM versions_table 
WHERE user_date between versions_table.from 
      AND versions_table.to;
```

With this you indicates that you mean columns from table `versions_table` and not the keyword `FROM`

Comment: or just put brackets `[from]` and `[to]`

Comment: Okay, that would be another way, Thanks!

Comment: @ArnelAves not in Oracle. You would use double-quotes instead, although the OP would then need to refer to that field with the correct capitalisation and the double-quotes from then on. Much easier to change the column name to something like from_date and to_date.

Answer (score 1):

Try. I am assuming "user_date" is a column in versions_table

```
    select version from versions_table v where user_date=(select user_date from versions_table a where user_date between v.from and v.to);
```